# Ionic 2 Alert customization

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic-popup

I want to customize my alerts in Ionic 2. I know that I can do it globally in the variables.scss, but I want to modify a specific one, in a specific page.

I tried cssClass in the alert code, I tried other different things, that work, but globally, not for a specific one.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Edit all your `AlertController.create` methods to look like this:

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: title,
    subTitle: msg,
    buttons: ['OK'],
    cssClass: 'alertCustomCss' // <- added this
});
```

And add this to `app.scss`:

```
.alertCustomCss {
    // text color for basic alerts
    color: white; 

    // alert modal page bg color. Warning this will remove the alert transparency
    background-color: color($colors, dark, base); 

    button {
        color: white !important; // button text color
        background-color: color($colors, secondary, base) !important;
            //button bg color
    }

    .alert-message {
        color: white; // text color for confirm alerts
    }

    .alert-wrapper {
        background-color: color($colors, dark, base); // bg color of alert content
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the styles in `app.css` and calling it in `page.ts`

```
showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

In App.css

```
.alertCustomCss{
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  button{
      color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you created your specific page (let's call it `Sample1`) with the ionic CLI command `ionic g page Sample1`, you will find in your project a directory called Sample1 with 3 files: `Sample1.html`, `Sample1.ts` and `Sample1.scss`.

In `Sample1.scss` you will find:

```css
sample1-page {

}
```

In that place you must define your custom css class or redefine the ionic element style and all your styles will have scope only onto the Sample1 page.

Hope this could help you

### **UPDATE**

As [Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254681/duannx) mentions the alert components are not child of your page so if you put the css class into the specific page .scss file it will not be applied to the alert but if you put it into `app.scss` it will be applied. So this is an example:

**app.scss**

```css
.alertCustomCss{
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  button{
      color: blue;
  }
}
```

**Sample1.html**

```html
<button ion-button block outline (click)="showAlert()">Alert</button>
<button ion-button block outline (click)="showAlert2()">Alert2</button>
```

**Sample1.ts**

```js
  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  showAlert2() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Now you will see that the button "Alert" will show a customized alert while the button "Alert2" will show the alter with the default css style

Comment: You might want to note that the selector property in the component determines the element name.

Comment: Hi, I know where I need to do it, the thing is, that I can't modify an alert if its not globally, I already tried what you said, I know the classes that the alert uses, but even if I override them, the alert still remains the same.

Comment: You can not add style for alert inside `some-page.scss` because alert is not a child of your page. Just inspect it in chrome and see. So add style into `app.scss` is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Just add any name you want in cssClass of alert as i named **alertCustomCss**

```
logOut() {
  this.alrtCtrl.create({
                title: "Log out ?",
                message: "Are you sure to logout?",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        role: 'cancel',
                        handler: () => {
                        //something to do 
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Confirm",
                        handler: () => {
                            //log Out

                        }
                    }
                ],
                cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
            }).present();
```

Adding Styles to **alertCustomCss** class

```
.alertCustomCss{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    button{
        color: green!important;
    }
    .alert-wrapper{
        background: yellow;
    }
    .alert-message {
        color: skyblue;
    }
    .alert-title{
        color: black;
    }
}
```

View Image after applying above style => [Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dSJsxAgH-Xmz1DSL5XP1lNQ_Ef6I7eRy/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Though this is coming from Ionic 3, but you could always put the style outside of the `page-something` block from your something.scss file if you still want to keep local changes in your local files instead of the app.scss.

```
.alert-style{
    padding-left: 16px;
}

page-something{
}
```