# Setting default style of Ionic alert popup elements

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I followed the answers found here: [Ionic 2 Alert customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497778/ionic-2-alert-customization)

But I can't find all the other classes or elements that have to be styled so alerts look like I want.

I edited my code so it looks like this:

app.scss:

```
.alertCustomCss {
  background-color: color($colors, dark, base);
  color: white;
  button {
      color: white !important;
  }
}
```

ts:

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: title,
    subTitle: msg,
    buttons: ['OK'],
    cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
});
alert.present();
```

But this makes all the text white, replaces the transparency of the modal page that holds the popup and sets it to set 'background-color' (so the page that called the popup is not visible anymore). The text of the button is set to white.

*Please notice that the background around the popup is not transparent anymore.*

[image]

**The question is** how to set the background color of the text placeholder and not the whole page? What css properties to use?

**Broader question**: What are the elements (css classes or directives) of the alert popup that can be styled? Title text color, content text font, etc..

Comment: All element in the page can be styled by css. So you just need to find the class and add your style. If it does not work so your style is wrong. You need to find a way to correct it. It is just html and css, no need Ionic knowledge. Remember, some style need `!important` to override

Comment: @Duannx Thank you for the advice. Do you know what css properties do I have to set to change the background of an ionic alert window? What did you use to change yours? Or even better where can I find that info? The docs don't say much about this

Comment: Just inspect your element in browser dev tool. You will find all class what you need to style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited all my `AlertController.create` methods to look like this:

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: title,
    subTitle: msg,
    buttons: ['OK'],
    cssClass: 'alertCustomCss' // <- added this
});
```

And I added this to `app.scss`:

```
.alertCustomCss {
    color: white; // text color for basic alerts
    button {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: color($colors, secondary, base) !important;
    }
    .alert-message {
        color: white; // text color for confirm alerts
    }
    .alert-wrapper {
        background-color: color($colors, dark, base);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you enclosed the desired word in "span" like:

```
title: <span class='myAlertTitle'>Special Dogs</span>
```

and then you add that class in the app.scss normally, it will apply even you don't define cssClass attribute to the Alert Object.

It's not the OOTB way but you have more control over the style, I think...