# Ionic 3 alertCtrl custom cssClass not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I followed the official documentation and my code is like below:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Alert',
  subTitle: 'Subtitle',
  message: 'This is an alert message.',
  buttons: ['OK'],
  cssClass: 'profalert'
});

alert.present();
```

and my CSS:

```
.profalert{
    color:#e7333c;
    background-color: red;

}
```

But this is not changing the alertbox color. I also tried `alert .setCssClass('profalert');`

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497778/ionic-2-alert-customization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working fine.You just need to declare it inside the `app.scss` file.

*app.scss*

```
.profalert{
    color:#e7333c;
    background-color: red;

}
```

**Result:**

When I applied your style to my app's alert box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was adding the css in the page.scss. its working after adding the css inside app.scss.

Comment: any idea why it should be in app.css?

Comment: You need to apply it globally. Then only it works. @George

Comment: okay thank you, i was just wondering why... i believe its a matter of priority or something

Answer (score 6):

## If you're working with Ionic 4 then add:

```
.profalert{
color:#e7333c;
background-color: red;
}
```

to **global.scss**

If interested in **horizontal alignment** of alert control buttons, check my answer [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/align-3-buttons-in-alert/119984/3?u=salad-gg)

If you're migrating from older versions to ionic 4.x, check out [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#icon) repo for **breaking changes.**

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the previous answers, you can actually do it in your page.css but it needs to be outside of the page-name{ } like so:

```
page-name{

}

.profalert{
    color:#e7333c;
    background-color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.profalert {
    color:#e7333c;
    background-color: red;
}
```

1.add scss-class in global.scss in ionic4, 
2.add scss-class in app.scss in ionic3,
you should add scss-class in root scss file

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the CSS of a specific page is scoped only to elements of that page. Even though the Alert can be presented from within a page, the ion-alert element is appended outside of the current page. This means that any custom styles need to go in a global stylesheet file. In an Ionic Angular starter this can be the **src/global.scss** file or you can register a new global style file by adding to the styles build option in angular.json.[Style Placement](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert/#style-placement)