# Changing styles and text modification of alert controller in ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

[image]

Actually my alert controller "Title" is too lengthy , so i want to resize the text and i added Css class then tried to change the style in SASS by giving font size to it  unfortunately didn't worked and the buttons text are uppercase.So is there anyway to change font size of text ,buttons color and size and changing button text to lowercase?

**My typescript file**

```
import { IonicPage,AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-kpi',
  templateUrl: 'kpi.html',
})
export class KpiPage {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  temp2:any;
  lastUpdate:any;

 constructor(
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public menuCtrl : MenuController,


   ) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {

              this.refreshbutton();

      }
    });


refreshbutton(){

    this.getSession();

  if(this.offline == true)
    {
       this.offlineRefreshAlert();
    }  
   else{
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Do you really want to refresh the widgets?',
            message: 'Refresh process will take time to complete.',
            cssClass: 'alertLogCss',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                  alert = null;
                }
              },
              {
                text: 'Refresh now',
                 handler: () => {
                   if(this.online == true){
                      this.refreshdata(this.result.sid);
                      this.loadingrefreshdashboard();
                   }
                   if(this.offline == true){

                      this.offlineRefreshAlert();
                   }



                 }
               }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
    }

}
```

My SASS(CSS) file

```
.alertLogCss{
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4px;
  button{
      color: red;
      font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet of this using codepen/jsfiddle/plunker etc? it would be faster to answer.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KewExL

Comment: where is popup? I can not see in the output.

Comment: i think adding alert controller in codepen or jsfibble is too difficult, alertcontroller is in main app module

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47282729/4826457

Comment: yeh...but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 1):

You have to add css out of that's page scss block

```
.alertLogCss{
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    font-size: 4px;
    button{
        color: red !important;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-transform: lowercase !important;
    }
  }
```

Put in app.scss

Comment: it's already on app.scss....Is it possible to add a image or icon in alertcontroller?

Comment: You can write message property like this message: '<div><img src="https://uploads/category/category_logo/thumbnail/catgory_logo_1522302770.png"> Refresh process will take time to complete.</div>',

Comment: Actually text-transformation directly to lower case is there any way the make first letter uppercase like "Refresh Now".....

Comment: For that, you can write text-transformation = "capitalize !important"